# Alguien que me explique lo que imprime esto

Tags: java

Alguien es tan amable de explicarme lo que imprimen estas dos lineas de código en java:

```
System.out.println(5&6)
System.out.println(2|1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Son operadores a nivel de bits por ejemplo:

```
int a = 5;  //a = 101
int b = 6;  //b = 110

System.out.println(a&b); //4=100
System.out.println(a|b); //7=111
```

lo que hace es tomar el numero 0 como false y el 1 con true y completa la operacion con el operador logico que tu le ubiques.

AND o &: necesita ambos verdaderos(1) para que sea verdadero(1).

OR o |: Necesita que uno de los dos sea verdadero(1) para que la operacion sea verdadera.

Comment: Gracias amigo, justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @DanielCano Para servirte.